# How to check if Zend Optimizer or Zend Guard Loader is installed

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-optimizer, zend-guard

Through phpinfo you can see all kinds of php information. If you see this: 
[image]

then it means you have Zend Engine. But what it doesn't say is whether you use Zend Optimizer or Zend Guard Loader.

How can you check if one of these is installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see whether Zend optimizer is installed by phpinfo like this:

[image]

Simply google for pictures "phpinfo zend optimizer" and you will get many results on what it looks like.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Don't confuse ZEND Engine with ZEND Optimizer! They both are completely different. You need to install ZEND Optimizer separately.

If you had properly installed ZEND Optimizer. Then you could find the below similar line on your php.ini.

> Zend Engine vX.Y.Z, copyright (c) 1998-2006, Zend Technologies Ltd., 
>   with the Zend Optimizer vX.Y.Z, copyright (c) 1998-2006 Zend
>   Technologies  Ltd.

Simply do a search on your php.ini for this line: `Zend Optimizer`.

(or)

Checking existence of ZEND Optimizer through code:

```
<?php
echo function_exists('zend_optimizer_version')?'Yes':'No';
```

Comment: Maybe he has installed Zend Optimizer, what would the phpinfo look like then?

Comment: But can you read from the phpinfo that Zend Optimizer is installed?